# AttributeError : lower not found

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, stochastic

I am doing Document Classification  and obtained accuracy upto 76%. And while predicting the document category i did following one

```
doc_clf.predict(tf_idf.transform((count_vect.transform([r'document']))))
```

and i get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py", line 115, in <lambda>
  out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 306, in predict
  Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 923, in transform
  _, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, fixed_vocab=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 792, in _count_vocab
  for feature in analyze(doc):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 266, in <lambda>
  tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 232, in <lambda>
  return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 647, in __getattr__
  raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
```

How do i correct this error ? And any other way to improve the accuracy further?

I share link to review full code
[Full Code](https://www.github.com/Madhivarman/DR/blob/master/classify.py)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, `doc_clf` is a pipeline. So the `tf_idf.transform()` and `count_vect.transform()` will be handled automatically by the pipeline.

You should only call

```
category = doc_clf.predict([r'document'])
```

As this document passes through the pipeline, it will be automatically transformed by the CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek Kumar it worked..Any suggestions to improve classification accuracy??